# JDBC SQL Server raised error handling in multi statement stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have a multi-statement stored procedure that first performs a select and then raises an error if certain conditions are met.

The raise error in the stored procedure doesn't cause a JDBC SQLException like I expect however.

If I remove the SELECT, then it works fine.  [The same type of behavior occurs with the print statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989302/java-is-not-catching-ms-sql-stored-procedure-raise-error)

I have multiple other ways to handle this, but for future reference I was wondering if there was a way to check if raised errors do exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the SQL server protocol works, you first need to process the result set produced by the select, and then move to the next result to get the exception.

To process all results (result sets, update counts and exceptions), you need do something like:

```java
CallableStatement csmt = ...;
boolean isResultSet = cstmt.execute();
do {
   if (isResultSet) {
       // process result set
       try (ResultSet rs = csmst.getResultSet()) {
           while(rs.next()) {
               // ...
           }
       }
   } else {
       int updateCount = rs.getUpdateCount();
       if (updateCount == -1) {
           // -1 when isResultSet == false means: No more results
           break;
       } else {
           // Do something with update count
       }
   }
   isResultSet = cstmt.getMoreResults();
} while(true);
```

When the execution of the stored procedure reaches the exception, this will also report the exception to your java application (iirc from `getMoreResults()`).